# Limitar acceso a rutas no existentes en angular

Tags: angular, url, rutas, parametros

A partir de una ruta con parámetros, si el usuario introduce el parámetro directamente en la URL, el componente lo carga igualmente.
Por ejemplo:

```js
// app-router.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: InicioComponent },
  { path: 'inicio', component: InicioComponent },
  { path: ':modelo', component: ProductoComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
];


//producto.componente.ts
export class ProductoComponent implements OnInit {

  producto: {
    modelo: string
  }

  listaProductos = ['modelS','model3','modelX','modelY','powerWall','carga'];

  constructor(
    private rutaActiva: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let paramRoute = this.rutaActiva.snapshot.params.modelo;

    if (this.listaProductos.indexOf(paramRoute) != -1) {

      this.producto = {
        modelo: this.rutaActiva.snapshot.params.modelo
      };

      this.rutaActiva.params.subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.producto.modelo = params.modelo;
        }
      );
     }
    }
```

La finalidad es que si se escribe directamente en la URL, redireccione, en caso de que no exista.

Comment: 'inicio' y `:modelo` se solapan. `inicio` se va a tomar como un parámetro. Puedes agregar antes algo como `listar/:modelo`. Y a donde quieres redirigir?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.
Pero lo que quiero evitar, es que el usuario, no pueda escribir la URL y le lleve a una pagina que no existe, pero si que crea todos los elementos.
En mi ejercicio, no quiero que puedan escribir en la barra de navegación por ejemplo: listar/model5 en caso de que "model5" no exista. En este caso, quiero que se redirija a otra ruta.
Disculpa si no me explico muy bien...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso de que el elemento no exista, con la lógica del componente puedes redireccionar.

```js
constructor(
  private rutaActiva: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router

) {}
//...
//Mas codigo
//...

this.rutaActiva.params.subscribe(
  (params: Params) => {

    if (existeModelo(params.modelo)) {
      this.producto.modelo = params.modelo;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(["/rutaPadre", "inicio"])
    }
  }
);

//...


existeModelo(params.modelo) {
  return //Alguna funcion que compruebe si existe. 
}
```